# Getting data from a different website using file_get_contents

Tags: php, extract, file-get-contents

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.101?action=edit 
This is the website I'm trying to get data from. This data is free to use it isn't copyrighted.
This is what i do right now but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$leagueoflegendswebsite = file_get_contents($_POST['leagueoflegendswebsite']);
    $first_step = explode( '<textarea>' , $leagueoflegendswebsite );
    $second_step = explode("</textarea>" , $first_step[0] );
    echo $second_step[1];
```

For example right now I would like to get the names of the champions from this website so

```
{{ci|Sona|Sona, the Maven of the Strings}}


{{ci|Blitzcrank}}
```

it would be Sona and Blitzcrank and is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you getting any results as of now?

Comment: @VIDesignz right now I'm getting an error but If i change second_step to 0 it will display me the whole website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$leagueOfLegendsWebsiteHtml = file_get_contents("http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.101?action=edit");

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/{{ci\|([^\|||}]+)/', $leagueOfLegendsWebsiteHtml, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Should get the names using regexp.

Results are:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{ci|Sona
            [1] => {{ci|Sona
            [2] => {{ci|Blitzcrank
            [3] => {{ci|Fiddlesticks
            [4] => {{ci|Garen
            [5] => {{ci|Gragas
            [6] => {{ci|Jax
            [7] => {{ci|Karthus
            [8] => {{ci|Kennen
            [9] => {{ci|Kassadin
            [10] => {{ci|Katarina
            [11] => {{ci|Kog'Maw
            [12] => {{ci|Rammus
            [13] => {{ci|Shaco
            [14] => {{ci|Singed
            [15] => {{ci|Taric
            [16] => {{ci|Twitch
            [17] => {{ci|Vladimir
            [18] => {{ci|Zilean
            [19] => {{ci|Ebonmaw
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sona
            [1] => Sona
            [2] => Blitzcrank
            [3] => Fiddlesticks
            [4] => Garen
            [5] => Gragas
            [6] => Jax
            [7] => Karthus
            [8] => Kennen
            [9] => Kassadin
            [10] => Katarina
            [11] => Kog'Maw
            [12] => Rammus
            [13] => Shaco
            [14] => Singed
            [15] => Taric
            [16] => Twitch
            [17] => Vladimir
            [18] => Zilean
            [19] => Ebonmaw
        )

)
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => {{ci|Sona [1] => {{ci|Sona [2] => {{ci|Blitzcrank [3] => {{ci|Fiddlesticks [4] 
Thats the result close but not it yet I'll try to play with it

Comment: Updated with results outputted by my script, you should be able to get what you want from the array in $matches[1]

Comment: is there a way to first cut out from this whole page just the Champions paragraph and then from it cut out name of the champions and so on?

Comment: Not easily, why? What info do you want?

Comment: Well in the end I want to get from this an array with all champion names champion spells and changes made to those spells so I can use it on my own website It will be quite a lot of sorting f

Comment: that part I've already figured out I will probably use regex a bunch to get everything that I want and then a lot of substrings

Comment: The regex /=== Champions ===([^===]+)/ gets just the champions area btw